# Connecting to a linux server running MySQL from a windows .NET server, ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, ado.net

Can I connect to a Ubuntu server, that is running MySQL using ADO.NET or do I need a special driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the [MySQL Connector/NET](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) ADO.NET driver.

Once installed, it behaves almost identically to Microsoft's native `System.Data.SqlClient`.  Instead of importing that namespace, use MySQL's:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

...

MySqlConnection DB = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=...");
```

Basically, just prepend `My` where you'd use any of the MS `SqlClient` classes.

Answer (score 1):

You use [Connector/NET](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).